# Arrow operator usage in Haxe and other variable type related questions

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I am following a tutorial for HaxeFlixel which uses the Haxe language. Now I do not have any experience in Haxe, but I decided to brave the tutorial since I do have experience in Java and Haxe as a language seems weirdly similar to Java.

So far, it was going smoothly. However, I came across this piece of code and I have several questions:

```
 class FSM
 {
     public var activeState:Void->Void;

     public function new(?InitState:Void->Void):Void
     {
         activeState = InitState;
     }

     public function update():Void
     {
         if (activeState != null)
             activeState();
     }
 }
```

Now I understand that this is a class called `FSM` and has a variable called `activeState`.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the type of `activeState`? I would understand if was something like `activeState:Void` but what does the `->` accomplish? Is it used as a pointer? Is it a void pointer pointing to another void variable?
2. What does the `?` before the `InitState:Void->Void` signify?
3. After the if statement, the `activeState` is being called like a function using the parentheses. However, `activeState` is a variable and not a function. So what does the if statement do exactly?

Also another question:

```
public var playerPos(default, null):FlxPoint;
```

I understand `playerPos` is an instance of the `FlxPoint` class, but what does the `default` and `null` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The type is `Void->Void` - it's a [function type](http://haxe.org/manual/types-function.html), in this case a function that takes no arguments and returns `Void`.
2. `?` indicates an [optional argument](http://haxe.org/manual/types-function-optional-arguments.html). In this case it's equivalent to writing `new(InitState:Void->Void = null)`.
3. `activeState` is a variable, but it stores a function - like you guessed, `activeState()` calls it.

`(default, null)` indicates that `playerPos` is a [property](http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property.html). With `default` as the read access identifier and `null` as the write access identifier, it is read-only outside of the class it's defined in.